# Trocar css por parametro

Tags: angular

Versão do Angular: 8.2

Ola,

Estou tentando trocar o CSS, toda vez que trocar um parametro (empresa).
Cada empresa tem o seu tema, por exemplo, empresa A o tema é vermelho, portanto, em certas partes da view serão vermelhas, ja na empresa B o tema é verde...

Eu tentei criar uma propriedade:

`cssEstilos: { [key: string]: string } = {};`

E no meu construtor:

```
cssEstilos = {
    background-color = "red"
}
```

No HTML:

```
<nav [ngStyle]="cssEstilos"> ...
```

Quando rodo a aplicação, não funciona e dai eu abro o inspecionar elemento e dentro do ngStyle eu tenho:

`ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

altere para:

```
cssEstilos = {     
   'background-color': 'red',  
};
```